# Please allow me to follow questions

Tags: feature-request, notifications, bookmarks, feed, follow-post

Sometimes I look a question that interests me, but I don't have the answer or would like to follow up later. Normally I just bookmark it, which then ends up in a big pile.

It would be great if there was a way to put a question in follow up, that I could later check my profile and get updates on the things I follow up.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "How do favorite questions work?" because for new users it is absolutely not transparent that the concepts of 'favorite' and 'follow' are identical. Especially since this is not the case on other platforms.

Comment: This is implemented see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network

Comment: There is also the new (2022) ['Saves' feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) (essentially multiple (named) lists of bookmarks)

Answer (score 16):

Why not just use the RSS feed at the bottom of the page?

I do this using Google Reader and it is incredibly simple and powerful.

There is also the favorite feature below the voting system, that will show up in your profile, but it will not alert you to changes.

Answer (score 13):

Do you perhaps wants something like a sign-up for a question, to perhaps a receive an e-mail with updates? I think it would be a cool feature...well, meantime, you can, as others pointed out, rss or favorite.

Answer (score 8):

Directly underneath the voting arrows on the question is a star.  If you click on the star, it will add it to your favorites.

You can view your favorites from your profile:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/######?tab=favorites#sort-top

There are also some interesting grease monkey scripts here on META too.

Comment: I'd like to get notification from it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried favoriting it by clicking the star below the votes?

Comment: Or do you mean that by "bookmark"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what is meant by bookmark, but in either case "followed" questions would end up in a similarly "big pile" so I don't see how it's a solution...

Comment: Ian Elliott, you are right about it becoming another big pile, but at least it is a different pile don't you think? I would think such an option like getting an email update like Enigma mentioned would be a good idea. Once you are satisfied with that questions and answer chain, you can remove it.

Comment: And the other thing with Bookmark is that it shows up as a extra count on the question. You wouldn't want to credit the question in the wrong way, would you?