# Following a question, any question

Tags: support, questions, tracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please allow me to follow questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13546/please-allow-me-to-follow-questions)

How do I follow a question? Is there some kind of trick that I'm not aware of where I can keep abreast of the answers posted to a question which may or may not be my own?

Answer (score 4):

There is a [question feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/38896) link at the bottom of the page.