# Adding a watch to a question

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)
>   ["Follow that question" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71842/follow-that-question-feature)
>   [Have an option to watch a question without posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20954/have-an-option-to-watch-a-question-without-posting)

Is it possible or is it a future enhancement that you can add a 'watch' - i.e. you are interested in the question but as yet have answered or made a comment - but wish it to be highlighted?

Answer (score 6):

You can always star it and come back to check it later, removing the star when you no longer care about them.

[image]

Comment: Details at [How do favorite questions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Comment: You really, really need to make this more visible! I had to earn my student badge to find that out!