# Follow a question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I am now following the Drupal tag with RSS, so I know when new question comes up. Some question are really interesting but I don't know the answer, and the question is still without an answer as I read the question too early. Is there a way to kind of follow the question and its answers, that allows me to get an email with the answers, when they are added?

Is the arrow up made for that or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but the star below the arrows is for just that purpose. (You won't get an email for incoming answers, but you will get notifications in the top bar.)

(In the past, there *was* an option to get email notification, but that has been removed.)

Comment: Unfortunately, as pointed out in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71842/follow-that-question-feature) and the comments on it/its answers, this is a rather poor workaround.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to make use of [filters and tagsets](https://stackexchange.com/filters/). Since questions based on a tag are sent via email every few hours - it's possible that most questions would have been answered by them.