# Is it possible to receive email update from favorites?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-exchange, email-notification

Here is my scenario:

i have a problem that is already in question on stackoverflow. i shouldn't add a comment to that question just to say "me too" and receive email updates. that is why i mark that question as "favorite" witch allows me to receive updates on the news feed.

the problem is: sometimes i stay almost a week not entering stackoverflow and because of that i really would like to receive this notifications by email.

in this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106380/165597 i found that i can create custom emails for some tags, but i couldn't find how make this "notification emails" for the favorites questions.

is there any way of doing it? a way to receive updates of questions that i`m not directly involved?