# Adding a button to temporarily follow a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Follow that question” feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71842/follow-that-question-feature)

I don't always comment on questions I'm interested in answering, but I do like to follow the development of said question because sometimes an edit or comment can lead to information that will help me answer said question so I tend to keep it open and refresh it, sometimes I do this with several questions.

Why not add a button to follow a question until it is resolved and get notified when new comments or edits are made on the question?

Comment: That's what that favorite "star" is for.

Comment: You don't get notified about comments or edits made to favorited question. And it's different, you tend to favorite questions that are either highly relevant, or very helpful to you, and tend to be answered.

Comment: You do actually. But they're easy to miss. For comments, the question will be highlighted in yellow at the top the first time you visit the tab. (just like the reputation tab when you get a vote) For edits, it gets both highlighted and bumped to the top of the list when filtered by "activity".

Comment: It is exactly a duplicate, I should probably delete this

Comment: Everyone seems to answer with the favorites button, and the objection of the OP in that question seems the same as mine, that favorite is exactly for that, marking a question as one of great use, not just to temporarily follow the development of the question until it's resolved.

Answer (score 4):

The favorite feature (or star) can serve your purpose. You won't receive a notification in your global inbox for favorited questions the way you do for responses or edits on your own questions and answers.

When you go to the "favorites" tab of your profile, however, you can sort by activity, which will put recently edited, answered, or commented questions at the top of your favorites list. Additionally, favorited questions that have had changes made since you last viewed the list will be highlighted. Here's an example from meta.photo.stackexchange.com:

[image]

The highlighted (green) question was edited since the last time I viewed my favorites tab on that site.

(Note: you can also view cross-site favorites by looking at your network profile. There won't be any highlighting there, but you can still sort by recent activity.)

Comment: I see, maybe it's just me, but I find this would generate too much bulk in my favorites, which for me are a curated list of useful questions. I just meant something that's volatile, just for the duration of the question and actually getting notified for it. Because then I'd have to be watching my favorites list and not actually viewing the stream for questions I might be interested in answering.

Comment: @8vius Sure. It's not a perfect fit because it wasn't designed to do explicitly what you're asking for. You can always unfavorite a question once you no longer find it helpful (just click the star again). What duration of time do you imagine this notification feature being active for? It sounds like you're expecting updates within minutes - which certainly happens on SO, but favorites are a network-wide feature, and a feature that's only useful for rapidly-updated posts wouldn't be very relevant for a lot of our smaller sites.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually referring to SO, that0's where I'm active. Also I said in my question, that the notifications arrive until an answer is accepted.

Comment: @slhck It's not a theme I'm using - it's the theme for Photography Stack Exchange. Every site that's graduated from beta has a different style; I used (meta)Photo.SE as an example because it was the first one I found that had changes to favorites I hadn't viewed yet. :)