# Option of following or keeping track of the questions which intrigues

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)
>   [Please allow me to follow questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13546/please-allow-me-to-follow-questions)

It would be better if there is an option available with user, where he can track the questions which intrigues him. For example, suppose one encounters a question which is not yet answered, and he wants to be intimated somehow, once an answer is given to that question (Imp: He is not the owner of that question, he is just curious to know what the answer could be, etc)

Comment: Did you happen to notice the star under the voting buttons?

Comment: Even if its not a fav question, users can track question which intrigues him(need not be favourtie ones).

Answer (score 0):

This already exists in the lower right corner for *each question*:

[image: RSS Feed Link]

This is an RSS feed link which is question specific.  For questions which you ask, you can also subscribe for updates via email.

**Note:** You can also favorite the question using the star icon below the up & down vote buttons.

Comment: RSS feed is to get complete updates. Can it be used for tracking single question ?

Comment: It *is* for a single question -- note that I just asked question number: 104008 and the RSS feed is: < http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/104008 >