# Managing followed questions

Tags: discussion, notifications, bookmarks, responses

I have set up a workflow where I star or favorite a question that I want to "follow".  I have found that this makes it easy for me to go back and see if there have been updates.  (I don't always get notifications of things going on in the question/answers.)  Then when I'm done or the question is answered, I remove it from my favorites.

Is there a better way?

I want to actually use favorites for what it was intended: Good answers that I want to refer back to in the future.  These don't always come up quickly on Google Search or the internal Stack Overflow search.

These are similar questions, but not exactly the same.  Some are old and seem to be no longer applicable.

1. [Subscribing to questions and comments that don't belong to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you)
2. [Rename "favorite" questions to "subscribed" or "following"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53124/rename-favorite-questions-to-subscribed-or-following)
3. [Please allow me to follow questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13546/please-allow-me-to-follow-questions)
4. [How do question bookmarks work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Comment: +1, I'd like a way to 'follow' a question and get notified in the top left when there's a comment, new answer, etc in the same way that if I post an answer and a comment gets added to it, I get notified.

Comment: Questions have RSS feeds, but you only see answers, not comments.